# strsplit by parentheses

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a string like "A B C (123-456-789)", I'm wondering what's the best way to retrieve "123-456-789" from it.

```
strsplit("A B C (123-456-789)", "\\(")
[[1]]
[1] "A B C" "123-456-789)"
```

Comment: This gets you the number `strsplit(str1, '[()]')[[1]][2]` but it is based on knowing the position beforehand.

Comment: or `strsplit("A B C (123-456-789)", "\\(|\\)")[[1]][2]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we want to extract the digits with `-` between the braces, one option is `str_extract`.  If there are multiple patterns within a string, use `str_extract_all`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(str1, '(?<=\\()[0-9-]+(?=\\))')
 #[1] "123-456-789"
 str_extract_all(str2, '(?<=\\()[0-9-]+(?=\\))')
```

In the above codes, we are using regex lookarounds to extract the numbers and the `-`.  The positive lookbehind `(?<=\\()[0-9-]+` matches numbers along with `-` (`[0-9-]+`) in `(123-456-789` and not in `123-456-789`.  Similarly the lookahead ('[0-9-]+(?=\)') matches numbers along with `-` in `123-456-789)` and not in `123-456-798`.  Taken together it matches all the cases that satisfy both the conditions `(123-456-789)` and extract those in between the lookarounds and not with cases like `(123-456-789` or `123-456-789)`

With `strsplit` you can specify the `split` as `[()]`.  We keep the `()` inside the square brackets to `[]` to treat it as characters or else we have to escape the parentheses (`'\\(|\\)'`).

```
 strsplit(str1, '[()]')[[1]][2]
 #[1] "123-456-789"
```

If there are multiple substrings to extract from a string, we could loop with `lapply` and extract the numeric split parts with `grep`

```
 lapply(strsplit(str2, '[()]'), function(x) grep('\\d', x, value=TRUE))
```

Or we can use `stri_split` from `stringi` which has the option to remove the empty strings as well (`omit_empty=TRUE`).

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_split_regex(str1, '[()A-Z ]', omit_empty=TRUE)[[1]]
 #[1] "123-456-789"

 stri_split_regex(str2, '[()A-Z ]', omit_empty=TRUE)
```

Another option is `rm_round` from `qdapRegex` if we are interested in extracting the contents inside the brackets.

```
 library(qdapRegex)
 rm_round(str1, extract=TRUE)[[1]]
 #[1] "123-456-789"
 rm_round(str2, extract=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
 str1 <-  "A B C (123-456-789)"
 str2 <- c("A B C (123-425-478) A", "ABC(123-423-428)",
 "(123-423-498) ABCDD", 
  "(123-432-423)", "ABC (123-423-389) GR (124-233-848) AK")
```

Answer (score 8):

or with `sub` from `base R`:

```
sub("[^(]+\\(([^)]+)\\).*", "\\1", "A B C (123-456-789)")
#[1] "123-456-789"
```

Explanation:

`[^(]+` : matches anything except an opening bracket
`\\(` : matches an opening bracket, which is just before what you want
`([^)]+)` : matches the pattern you want to capture (which is then retrieved in `replacement="\\1"`), which is anything except a closing bracket
`\\).*` matches a closing bracket followed by anything, 0 or more times

***Another option with look-ahead and look-behind***

```
sub(".*(?<=\\()(.+)(?=\\)).*", "\\1", "A B C (123-456-789)", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "123-456-789"
```

Answer (score 5):

The capture groups in `sub` will target your desired output:

```
sub('.*\\((.*)\\).*', '\\1', str1)
[1] "123-456-789"
```

Extra check to make sure I pass @akrun's extended example:

```
sub('.*\\((.*)\\).*', '\\1', str2)
[1] "123-425-478" "123-423-428" "123-423-498" "123-432-423" "124-233-848"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this also:

```
 k<-"A B C (123-456-789)"
     regmatches(k,gregexpr("*.(\\d+).*",k))[[1]]
[1] "(123-456-789)"
```

With suggestion from @Arun:

```
regmatches(k, gregexpr('(?<=\\()[^A-Z ]+(?=\\))', k, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
```

With suggestion from @akrun:

```
regmatches(k, gregexpr('[0-9-]+', k))[[1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try these gsub functions.

```
> gsub("[^\\d-]", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "123-456-789"
> gsub(".*\\(|\\)", "", x)
[1] "123-456-789"
> gsub("[^0-9-]", "", x)
[1] "123-456-789"
```

Few more...

```
> gsub("[0-9-](*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "123-456-789"
> gsub("(?:(?![0-9-]).)*", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "123-456-789"
```